# How to see the values of a relationship field with get in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I know I can easily see the value of a non-relationship field with `model_item.get('field')`, but how can I see the values of a relationship field? If I use `console.log` to print it out, it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`console.log( model.get('field').toArray() );`